# Выравнивание по центру страницы

Tags: html, css, javascript

align="center" уже не актуален, а что дали в замену? Как выровнять страницу по центру?
margin: 0 auto; не дает результата. Можно  margin:  0 (число)px; это реально, только если знать разрешение дисплея и ширину страницы.

margin:  0 (разрешение дисплея - ширина страницы) px; Но как узнать разрешение дисплея и ширину страницы? И как это впихнуть в margin (там можно вводить только 1  число, а не выражение).

У меня все в 1 большом диве с ИД main,

```
main{                         
position: absolute;
margin:  0 10px;
top: 0px;     
width:  1240px;
height:    1600px;
z-index: 1;   
text-align: left;
}
```

разрешение дисплея - 1280x1024 ширина страницы - 1240 => чтоб страница была у меня по центру (1280-1240)/2=10 => margin:  0 10px;

Comment: дай полный код страницы и css

Comment: у меня все в 1 большом диве с ИД main ,
main{                         
position: absolute;
margin:  0 10px;
top: 0px;     
width:  1240px;
height:    1600px;
z-index: 1;   
text-align: left;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В дополнение к ответу [[@Zhukov Roman](/users/10590/zhukov-roman)](/users/10590/zhukov-roman)...

Если необходимо, чтобы элемент был с position: absolute, то используйте такой вариант:

```
main{                         
  position: absolute;
  width: 1240px;
  height: 1600px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -620px;
  z-index: 1;   
  text-align: left;
}
```

Не забудьте перед main поставить "**.**" или **id** в зависимости от того какой у Вас селектор.

Удачи

Comment: Спасибо,все получилось.

Comment: @Олег24, удачи

Answer (score 6):

Конечно не будет выравниваться с *margin: 0 auto;* ведь вы указали *position: absolute;*

```
main{                         
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;  
  width: 1240px;
  height: 1600px;
}
```