# Какие свойства задать для блока, чтобы он располагался по центру страницы

Tags: css

Делаю фиксированный блок для меню.

```
.header-fixed {
    position: fixed
    z-index: 1000
    background-color: #ffffff
    top: 0
}
```

Вопрос: как расположить блок по центру при любых разрешениях экрана?

Comment: `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);`

Comment: спасибо, помогли

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выравнивание по центру страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/175012/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.header-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```